# python: semaphore protection on a list or a dict in python class

Tags: python

my code

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = {}
        self.y = []
        self.semaphore = threading.Semaphore()
    def __semaphore(func):
        def wrapper(**args. *kw):
            args[0].__sync_semaphore.acquire()
            ret = func(*args, **kw)
            args[0].__sync_semaphore.release()
            return ret
       return wrapper

    @__semaphore
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    @__semaphore
    def save_to_disk(self):
        """ access to my_class.x and my_class.y """

my_class = myclass()
my_class.x['a'] = 123
```

With the code above, I'm trying to use semaphore to protect my `x` and `y` when ever `save_to_disk` is called. But when I call `my_class.x['a'] = 123` , `my_class.__setattr__` is not called. So that my `x` is not protected.

I have 2 question:

- when I call `my_class.x['a'] = 123` which python function is called?
- how can I protect my `x` and `y` in `my_class` only, not global
  `list` and `dict`; my `x` and `y` might also have a `list` or a `dict` inside of it.

**Update:**
I want to update some concept for the random code above.
I want to create a kernel-like AI. The AI must to do 2 work at the same time. One is collecting all information that I give it. Two is that it has to save the information to disk when the threshold is reach (i do not want it to kill my RAM)

**What I'm tried to do**

- Creating a `class` that inherit `dict` and `list`, to override `{}` and `[]`, but it need me to update all `{}` and `[]`. That is not efficiency.
- Currently I'm trying to create a read/write semaphore and then override `dict().__setitem__`, `list.append`,etc. But I do not know what will come

Comment: A1: You can't run ``my_class.x['a'] = 123`` since my_class is a class, and it doesn't have an attribute of x.

Comment: A2: see the ``property decorator`` may help for you

Comment: @CarsonArucard I just give an implicit that `my_class = myclass()`, sorry if that confuse

Comment: and i'm aware of @property decorator but if it is not that I've  mistaken, that decorator will no help for list and and dict

Comment: Do you want to protect x and y or do you want to protect *their content*? What if x and y are nested data structures - would you need to protect the content of their content (and so on) as well? Why do you even want to modify (and thus synchronize) x and y directly, instead of having myclass handle this-e.g. via a queue.Queue?

Comment: I think this involves practical problems. If you want to get better suggestions, I suggest you put the real problems up.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want to protect it and its content, as least everytime it have new member, lost a member.

Comment: @CarsonArucard I do not think that I understand your meaning. But I have tried to override `[]` and `{}` with new `list` and `dict`, and failed x.x

Comment: I don't see the motivation for doing this from your demo,
I mean you don't want to just write a Hello World,
The variables x and y both seem to be named randomly,
From the code you provided, I only know that you might want to keep something to the desktop,
the code is written for demonstration purposes only.
Such questions reduce the willingness to participate,
Even if someone answers your question, it will be of little help to most people because they don't know what the real application is.

Comment: In other words, I want to know what application you want to make, so maybe we can understand why you have to do it.

Comment: @CarsonArucard I have update some of my concept to the question. Although it really hard to keep the privacy of the original idea. The original idea owner will not happy if I give to much information online.

Comment: Just to get your question down to a clear problem description: in ˋmy_class.x['a'] = 123ˋ, do you want to protect ˋmy_class.x...ˋ (lookup of entire x) or ˋ...x['a'] = 123ˋ (assignment to x content)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi my final goal is that when ever  `my_class.x['a'] = 123` or even `my_class.x['a'][1] = 123`, no other thread can read `my_class.x`. And vice versa, when some thread read `my_class.x`, `my_class.x['a'] = 123` and `my_class.x['a'][1] = 123` have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: It is not useful to do this just on `myclass` methods since not only `myclass` is involved. `my_class.x['a'] = 123` is equivalent to this:

```
def set_x_a(obj: myclass, value):
    x = obj.__getattr__('x')   # fetch `x` via `myclass` method
    x.__setitem__('a', value)  # set `'a'` via `type(x)` method

set_x_a(my_class, 123)
```

Note how the call to `my_class.__getattr__` has already completed when `x.__setitem__` is called. Any synchronisation internal to `my_class` methods is thus of the wrong scope.

---

You can protect class fields from concurrent access by only giving access to them in synchronised blocks.

Python's basic means of synchronising blocks is the `with` statement, which for example [can be used with `threading` locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects). To simplify creating a custom block, [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) work with a single generator (instead of two methods). Finally, a [`property` allows to add behaviour to attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), such as synchronisation.

```
import sys
import threading
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Synchronized:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = {}  # actual data, stored internally
        self._mutex = threading.RLock()

    @property
    @contextmanager
    def x(self):           # public behaviour of data
        with self._mutex:  # only give access when synchronised
            yield self._x

    def save(self, file=sys.stdout):
        with self._mutex:  # only internally access when synchronised
            file.write(str(self._x))
```

The important change is that the `dict` attribute is no longer directly exposed. It is only available *with holding a lock*.

```
synced = Synchronized()
with synced.x as x:
    x['a'] = 123
    x['b'] = 42

synced.save()
```

You can extend this pattern to additional attributes, and improve the protection of attributes. For example, you can `yield` of a copy or [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) of `self._x`, and explicitly update the internal state with this at the end of the block -- thus invalidating the effect of external references afterwards.

Comment: Well, If I not wrong, when ever `my_class.x` or `my_class.x['a']` is called, the thread itself will acquire `Rlock` and release after `yield`. So if `a = some_object()` then `my_class.x['a'] = a`, when we access `a` without using `my_class.x` the `Rlock` will not occur?

Comment: Secondly, if I have multiple writing thread,  can the run asynchronously or the will wait other writing thread to complete?

Comment: @Silver Can you please clarify your questions? Your words are very hard to read/understand.

Comment: I'm currently not understand how `with` work in your second codeblock.  But if `a` is a member of `x` (like `x['a'] = a`), accessing `a` without calling it from `x['a']` will not trigger mutex, right?

Comment: @Silver The ``with`` of the second code block delegates to the ``with`` inside ``Synchronised.x`` -- the mutex is held for the entire inner *and* outer block. As for your other question, if a malicious code extracts/keeps a direct reference to an internal part of your data, there is no way to protect against it.

Answer (score -1):

### Q1

*when I call my_class.x['a'] = 123 which python function is called?*

call the `def __getattribute__(self, item):` first

### about your idea

*I want to create a kernel-like AI. The AI must to do 2 work at the same time. One is collecting all information that I give it. Two is that it has to save the information to disk when the threshold is reach (i do not want it to kill my RAM)*

The problem is because two threads want to share the same variable, right?

If so, maybe you can try to get only one thread working at a time, then don't worry about the resources be changing.

for example:

```
import threading
import numpy as np
from time import time, sleep


def get_data(share_list, share_dict):
    num_of_data = 0
    while num_of_data < 6:
        t_s = time()
        if is_writing_flag.is_set():
            sleep(REFRESH_TIME)
            continue

        while 1:
            data = np.random.normal(1, 1, (10,))
            threshold = all(data > 1.6)
            if threshold:
                share_list.append(data)
                share_dict['time'] = time() - t_s
                num_of_data += 1
                is_writing_flag.set()
                break
    close_keeper_flag.clear()


def data_keeper(share_list, share_dict):
    while close_keeper_flag.is_set():
        while is_writing_flag.is_set():
            # save as csv, json, yaml...
            print(share_list.pop())
            print(share_dict['time'])
            is_writing_flag.clear()
        sleep(REFRESH_TIME)


def main():
    share_list = []
    share_dict = {}
    td_collect_data = threading.Thread(target=get_data, name='collect some data', args=[share_list, share_dict])
    td_data_keeper = threading.Thread(target=data_keeper, name='save data.', args=[share_list, share_dict])
    for th in (td_collect_data, td_data_keeper):
        th.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    REFRESH_TIME = 0.2
    is_writing_flag = threading.Event()
    is_writing_flag.clear()

    close_keeper_flag = threading.Event()
    close_keeper_flag.set()
    main()
```

But I will prefer using the `asyncio` to handle this, for example

```
import asyncio
import numpy as np
from time import time


async def take_data(num_of_data):
    count = 0
    t_s = time()
    while 1:
        if count == num_of_data:
            break
        data = await collect_data()
        cost_time = time() - t_s
        yield list(data), dict(time=cost_time)
        t_s = time()
        count += 1


async def collect_data():
    while 1:
        data = np.random.normal(1, 1, (10,))
        threshold = all(data > 1.6)
        if threshold:
            break
    return data


async def ai_process():
    async for res_list, res_dict in take_data(5):
        print(res_dict['time'])
        # save_to_desktop()
        ...


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([ai_process()]))
    loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If this is still not useful to you at all, I will delete the answer. If you have any questions, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: The question isn’t about private/protected/public attributes. It‘s about protection from *concurrent* modification via synchronization.

Comment: It seems that question two is not what he wants. But I think I am right in answering the first question. His confusion is that he thinks that ``__setattr__`` should be executed. The reason why it is not executed is that ``my_class.x['a'] = 123`` first executes the function ``__getattribute__``. The return value is Dict. So the following action is Dict's ``__setitem__`` so that causes ``__setattr__`` to be useless.

Comment: I got a negative evaluation in the case of half right, I feel a bit cruel, but still, respect your decision.

Comment: The relevant method called for ``my_class.['a'] = 123`` is ``__setitem__`` *of type ``dict``*.